# Amazon EC2 PHP5 not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This seems to be weird, I installed `apache2`, `php5`, `phpmyadmin`, `mysql-server`.

I created a file with the code -

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then my web server output was same as the code string. It didn't output any of its php config.

I've used Google Cloud Platform, DigitalOcean.. New to Amazon EC2, but as this machine just being a linux, it should work all normal, but it isn't.

EDIT:

When I run this command `$php info.php` on my EC2 Instance command line, it shows the complete output of the phpinfo(); , but it isn't showing up on my browser.

Output of : `sudo apachectl -M`

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Comment: Do you have php5 module loaded (`apachectl -M`)?  Double check: [Apache 2.x on Unix systems](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php), if there is nothing obvious. Did you change any of its configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I just installed `libapache2-mod-php5` and enabled the php5 module by `sudo a2enmod php5`

and it all started working! :)